# Emojis don't render in question titles, but do render within questions

Tags: bug

Pretty sure that's not right...

[image: screen shot of missing emoji in title]

Link to the question in case anyone else wants to see -
 [How can I display the  emoji on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/1205451/how-can-i-display-the-emoji-on-windows)

Weirdly, it doesn't display properly in the edit dialog either:

[image: screen shot of edit dialog]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Oh hey there. Looks like that's [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1205451/how-can-i-display-the-emoji-on-windows) you've linked there. :P

[Michael Frank's answer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12393/emojis-dont-render-in-question-titles-but-do-render-within-questions/12394#12394) is entirely correct. As per the premise of my question, the  emoji renders incorrectly in both the title and body of the question. The Apple logo [image: apple symbol] there is actually an image uploaded to imgur to demonstrate what the emoji is *supposed* to look like.

In other words, I think we can safely count this as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: I'm not getting rid of this question, as it's an interesting situation to be aware of.

Comment: Ironically enough, while writing this post I discovered that [inline images don't display properly in SE's iOS app](https://i.imgur.com/lupRbVV_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=high).

Answer (score 8):

You dun goofed, son. That's an image.

[image]

Its been posted inline, pretty cleverly so people can see what it should look like

Comment: ... Should I link the question? XD - I was thinking that'd break at some point...

Comment: No, I mean the little Apple logo in his question is actually an in-line image.

Comment: [Here's the question](https://superuser.com/q/1205451/380318) - the working one is an inline image, while the box is the character.

Comment: I'm so confused now.

Comment: @djsmiley2k an emoji (specifically a special Unicode character) vs an inline image